# Minimum cost to reach point

Tags: dynamic-programming, number-theory

Given are positive integers `n, a, b, p[1], p[2], p[3]` (All `<= 10^9`). Suppose we are standing at position x=0, and we want to reach point n. We can move only to right. For 1 move, we can move by 1 at cost `p[1]`, move by `a` at cost `p[2]` and move by `b` at cost `p[3]`. The task is to find minimum cost if we can use this moves. There is no restrictions on number of moves.
The ideas I came up with are dynamic programming and linear equations with 3 variables. But still can't solve the problem.

UPD: Suppose also we are given with `T (T <= 50)` independent queries.

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail the dynamic programming idea you had, as well as the linear equation with 3 variables?

Comment: well, dynamic prog. idea: just dp(i) - minimum cost to reach point i;
linear equations: x + y * a + z * b = n; if we find this solutions maybe we can somehow find the minimum cost (the cost for (x, y, z) is x * p1 + y * p2 + z * p3)

Comment: Both ideas are great and each one of them can lead to a working algorithm if you explore them. So, you already had the good ideas. Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: dynamic programming solution is O(n) which is very bad (n <= 10^9).

Comment: for, linear equations I didn't come up with good idea to even find solutions :)

Comment: You want to minimize `x*p[1] + y*p[2] + z*p[3]`, under constraint `x + y * a + z * b = n`. Have you heard of [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming)? It's the subdiscipline concerned with solving problems involving minimizing a linear function, under linear equality/inequality constraints. In your case, x,y and z are required to be integers rather than real numbers, so this is a "integer linear programming" problem rather than a continuous linear programming problem.

Comment: If you hadn't heard about this before, then you should probably focus on the dynamic programming solution for now. And come back to the very interesting topic of linear programming afterwards ;)

Comment: wow, I think it is too hard for just interview problem)

Comment: Actually, linear programming is such a classic problem and there are so many good solvers available for linear programming, that an interviewer would probably be very pleased if you answered "here is how to formulate this problem as a linear programming problem" rather than actually writing out an algorithm yourself

Answer (score 0):

Think of the last step: it would be to move right by 1 unit, a units, or b units.  If the last step is to move right 1 unit, then the total cost is p[1]+mincost(n-1).  Similarly for the other two possibilities.

Thus, we get the recursive equation: mincost(n) = min{p[1]+mincost(n-1), p[2]+mincost(n-a), p[3]+mincost(n-b)}.  This can be implemented using top-down recursion with memoization or bottom-up dynamic programming.

Comment: Or Dijkstra, which is a particular case of almost-bottom-up-but-not-quite dynamic programming.

Comment: worst case is O(n)

Comment: @bere  yes, it is O(n). In fact it is $Theta(n)$.  Because step size of 1 is allowed, bottom-up would be faster than top-down recursion with memoization by a constant factor. (With other sets of step sizes, top-down could be faster because it would solve only the required subproblems rather than all all smaller subproblems like bottom-up does.)

Comment: okaay, I also forgot to mention that there are T <= 50 queries of this. and I am not sure it will work fast

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you had two ideas:

- using a recurrence relation to write a dynamic programming algorithm;
- solving a linear equation.

Both ideas are great. Since another answer already focuses on dynamic programming, I will focus on the linear equation.

Here is a reformulation of your problem:

```
MINIMIZE:
    x * p[1] + y * p[2] + z * p[3]

UNDER CONSTRAINTS:
    x + y * a + z * b = n
    x, y, z ≥ 0
    x, y, z are integers
```

This is an integer linear program. Formulating a problem as a linear program or as an integer linear program is a very useful skill. Congratulations!

If this is an interview question, the interviewer will probably be very happy with you simply formulating the problem as a linear program. Thus the "code" I wrote above would probably satisfy them.

There are many existing solvers for linear programs.

For instance, here is code in python, using library [PuLP](https://pypi.org/project/PuLP/):

```py
from pulp import LpProblem, LpVariable, LpMinimize

def min_cost_to_reach_point(n, a, b, p):
    x = LpVariable('x', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
    y = LpVariable('y', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
    z = LpVariable('z', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
    P = LpProblem('min_cost_to_reach_point', LpMinimize)
    P += x * p[0] + y * p[1] + z * p[2]
    P += x + y * a + z * b == n
    P.solve()
    return {'cost': P.objective.value(), 'steps_1': x.value(), 'steps_a': y.value(), 'steps_b': z.value()}

n = 100
a, b = 11, 17
p = (2, 20, 20)
print( min_cost_to_reach_point(n, a, b, p) )
# {'cost': 128, 'steps_1': 4, 'steps_a': 1, 'steps_b': 5}
```